# Use of cl-defun

Tags: help, defun, cl

What is a use case for `cl-defun`, where `defun` wouldn't work or would be hard to work with?  I am using it to count the number of opening and closing bracemarks.

```lisp
    (cl-defun rk-bracemark-count-from-char
        (brcmk-beg &optional brcmk-end
                             (rgn-beg (region-beginning))
                             (rgn-end (region-end)))
      "Count number of opening and closing brace marks.
    Search is applied within a region."
    
      (interactive
       (list (read-char-from-minibuffer "Opening Bracemark: ")
             (read-char-from-minibuffer "Closing Bracemark: ")
             (region-beginning)
             (region-end) ))
    
      (save-excursion
        (let ( ($count-begmk  0) ($count-endmk  0) 
               ($begmk  (char-to-string brcmk-beg))
               ($endmk  (and brcmk-end (char-to-string brcmk-end))) )
    
          (goto-char rgn-beg)
          (while (and (< (point) rgn-end)
                      (search-forward $begmk rgn-end t))
            (cl-incf $count-begmk))
    
          (goto-char rgn-beg)
          (while (and brcmk-end
                  (< (point) rgn-end)
                  (search-forward $endmk rgn-end t))
            (cl-incf $count-endmk))
    
          (message "Marks: %s %s  Counts: %d %d" $begmk $endmk
               $count-begmk $count-endmk)
          (goto-char rgn-beg) )))
```

Comment: The question encourages opinion-based answers. Maybe ask a more specific question, saying what it is about `cl-defun` that you don't understand etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cl-defun` if you want (as you do) default values for optional arguments or, with `&key`, keyword arguments.  There is more which you can find starting at `C-h f <RET> cl-defun`.